# Error while loading shared libraries: libmpv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, flet

I've installed flet through "pip install flet" from the terminal on Ubuntu. Upon running the basic flet code, just to check whether it worked this pops up:

`error while loading shared libraries: libmpv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The code I ran is:

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    # add/update controls on Page
    pass

ft.app(target=main)
```

I also followed the Linux system instructions from terminal to install flet:

> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio`

What can I try next? I'm relatively new to Ubuntu.

I expected a basic flet window to pop up, and not an error from the terminal. Something like:

[image: basic flet window the code was supposed to create]

Instead I got the error:

`error while loading shared libraries: libmpv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Actually ran into this issue today and came across your post whilst troubleshooting it.

What worked for me was installing libmpv by running:

```
sudo apt install libmpv1
```

After, you should be able to follow the flet introduction as intended.